# How do I get the program to accumulate total amount of points the user inputs each time?

Tags: java, arrays

```
package testB;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testB {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declare Variables
        String studentname = "";
        String coursename = "";
        int assignmentsubmitted = 0;
        int submitted = 0;
        int points = 0;
        int pt = 0;
        //Total points worth
        double tpw = 0;
        double score = 0;
        //Total score
        double ts = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to My Grade Calculator!");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter candidate name:  ");
        studentname = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter course name:  ");
        coursename = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter how many assignments were submitted: ");
        assignmentsubmitted = input.nextInt();
        if (assignmentsubmitted <= 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Must be a number and greater than 0! Try again.");
            assignmentsubmitted = input.nextInt();
        }

        do 
        {       
            int i = 1;
            do
            {
                System.out.println("How many points was assignment " + i + ":");
                i++;
                points = input.nextInt();
        }
```

It increments based on how many assignments user inputs `while (i <= assignmentsubmitted);`. 
I want it to calculate the points the user inputs so I can display it.
`points += pt;`

Comment: why you need two `do-while`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
points += input.nextInt();
```

Points will contain the sum of all input. is it what you want?